# Cryptlib won't encrypt with El-Gamal and I don't understand why?

Tags: security, cryptography, encryption

```
unsigned char * BUFFER_PTR;
CRYPT_CONTEXT cryptContext;

// Initialize the buffer
BUFFER_PTR = (unsigned char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * BUFFER_SIZE);
memset(BUFFER_PTR, 'X', BUFFER_SIZE);

//Initialize crytplib
cryptInit();
// create encryption context
cryptCreateContext( &cryptContext, CRYPT_UNUSED, CRYPT_ALGO_ELGAMAL);
cryptSetAttributeString( cryptContext, CRYPT_CTXINFO_LABEL, KEY_ID, strlen(KEY_ID));
cryptGenerateKey(cryptContext);

/* ERROR >>>*/ cryptEncrypt(cryptContext, BUFFER_PTR, BUFFER_SIZE); /* this line fails and I don't know why :-( */
```

Comment: Please be more specific. When you say that a line fails, what error code is it returning? Have you looked up that error code in the CryptLib documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling for `cryptlib CRYPT_ERROR_PARAM3` suggests that there was a problem with your third parameter. Now look at page 186 of the cryptlib manual, about `CryptEncrypt` for public-key algorithms:

> If the encrypted data length isn’t the same as the key size, the function will return CRYPT_ERROR_PARAM3 to indicate that the length is invalid.

I have never used cryptlib so this is an educated guess, but it looks rather like your plaintext isn't an appropriate size for the key you are using.